# Dropping table in Sql-Server using try-catch block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The code below works and is quite precise, but is it OK to do it like this as against the other 'standard' ways ?

```
--Drop table if exists
begin try
    drop table #temp
end try

begin catch 
    print 'table does not exist'
end catch

--Create table
create table #temp(a int, b int)
```

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. If you are just working with a temporary table then Pream's answer is as good as any. Your technique would give feedback on whether the table existed, and that feedback may be useful

Comment: Catch blocks are brilliant if you intend to take action when/if an exception occurs.  If there is no additional action, you could argue it's just extra typing.  In this case, I often don't care if the temp exists or not.  I am only checking to avoid an error.  With that in mind, the `IF NOT EXISTS/OBJECT_ID IS NULL` methods are more concise.

Comment: @destination-data  Looks like `Try catch` is overkill here. If one needs additional actions when table doesn't exist `if ... begin additional-actions end` will do.

Comment: I am sorry I did not mean just temporary tables, I just want feedback on whether this would be a good way to drop-create any table including temp ones.

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use

```
If Object_Id('Tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null
Drop Table #temp
create table #temp
```

As you intend to create a #temp Table ultimately which does not require try catch to give a error message that #temp Table does not exists

if the create statement was inside the try, it may have some use

Comment: Why?  I'm not necessarily disagreeing, but can you explain the benefits this approach offers?

Comment: Hi @destination-data, By the look of the code in the question, anonxen ultimately wants to create a temp table, which does not require try catch to give a error message that tempTable does not exists, in case if the create statement was inside the try, it may have some use

Comment: If your answer included that description, I'd definitely upvote it.

Comment: @destination-data, There you go!

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` statement, `IF` tables exists then only drop table. Otherwise create 
table directly:

```
BEGIN TRY
  IF Object_Id('Tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null
     DROP Table #temp
  CREATE table #temp
END try
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'table does not exist'
END CATCH
```

Comment: I'm getting older, I even started using glasses around the house and not just in front of the computer. I other words, I could be getting blind, but where exactly is EXISTS used in this suggestion? it says not null :)